# How can I map a "root" Servlet so that other scripts are still runnable?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, web.xml

I'm trying to build a Servlet that calls a JSP page similar to the following:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/main.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
```

I need this Servlet to respond to the domain's root (eg: http://example.com/) so I'm using the following mapping in the web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The problem I'm having is that this matches EVERYTHING, so when the dispatcher forwards to "/WEB-INF/main.jsp" this matches the url-pattern so the Servlet gets run again. This results in a loop that runs until it dies with a [java.lang.StackOverflowError](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html).

How can I match the root without preventing other scripts from being runnable?

Comment: you wont be able to do that you have to use hacks i tried the same on appengine see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet but not working

Comment: Maybe time for an accepted answer?

Answer (score 49):

Use an empty pattern, e.g.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern></url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The servlet 3.0 spec has clarified this:

> The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the
>   application's context root

So it should at least work on a 3.0 container, and I've verified that it works on Jetty 8

Comment: App engine is still on 2.5, so that's not surprising.

Comment: @nilskp so how to do it on app-engine? if I leave it empty it shows an error

Comment: @AhmadMuzakki perhaps try the answer from Jeb.

Comment: @nilskp This works on App Engine Flexible environment, since it's running Jetty 9.3 (Servlet 3.1).

Comment: Works for me using servlet-3.1 on was liberty

Comment: This work in eclipse neon j2ee project with tomcat9 server. Thanks a lot. "/" was not working.

Answer (score 29):

Using the welcome-file element of web.xml worked for me, **on app engine**. Here's mine:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RootServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.foo.RootServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RootServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>foo</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This works great. Just be aware the 'servlet-name' cannot be the same as the 'welcome-file'.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me on Jetty or Tomcat. Only when the welcome file is an actual file does it open it correctly.

Comment: Works like a charm in Apache Tomcat, even though the solution offered by @nilskp is a bit lighter :)

Comment: @Jus12 Any file that is named in the `web.xml` should be an existing file. Even if a servlet (or even a faclets file) is mapped to it.

Comment: Aaaaaah that's why my welcome file was not working ! The"/" need to be removed ! So if your servlet url-pattern is /Blabla your welcome file need to be "Blabla" without the "/". Great ! Best solution ! Thank you !

Answer (score 7):

The original question doesn't mention that they're trying to map a root servlet on App Engine - it's easy on Tomcat (and other servlet containers as far as I know) but App Engine isn't a normal servlet container.

My normal way of building a web application with servlets is to extend HttpServlet, add a "page" object with title, content, errors, messages etc. and for output forward to a JSP template.  This has been an absolute nightmare getting working in App Engine.

- JSP files can't be "named" without a "/" at the beginning.
- JSP files can't be in a subdirectory
- Servlets can't be mapped to the root of your application with a "/" url-pattern

Here's my web.xml (edited for brevity) which finally worked.

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <!-- this servlet needs to redirect to a NamedDispatcher
         called "template" -->
    <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.domain.HomeSv</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <!-- jsp file must apparently be in root directory and have "/" at
         start of path -->
    <servlet-name>template</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/template.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <!-- map your home servlet to somewhere other than "/" -->
    <servlet-name>Home</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <!-- make your Home servlet the welcome file -->
    <welcome-file>home</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I haven't been particularly scientific about validating all this - but it seems to work for me now and I'm pretty happy about that.

Comment: On the dev server, it seems that adding a fallback <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> will cause that index.html to take precedence over your servlet, if it exists, even if it is specified _after_ the <welcome-file>home</welcome-file>.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a welcome file named index.jsp in the root with the following code using JSTL or otherwise.

```
<c:redirect url="/main"/>
```

So in the web.xml file you will have this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>        
</welcome-file-list>
```

So anyone requesting the root will be redirected to /main. Now your servlet can be mapped to main.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/main</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Ok, I get that this would work, but it fells like such a hack. Is it really not possible to have a servlet handle the root on its own?

Comment: Sorry for voting down but there is a better solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030302/how-can-i-map-a-root-servlet-so-that-other-scripts-are-still-runnable/4443581#4443581

Comment: This solution has the advantage that it doesn't create a mapping in every directory, the way welcome-files do.  So I used it (though with plain <% scriptlet, not a tag) and I'm voting it up.

Answer (score 1):

Try just to remove '*' from the pattern, i.e.

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

Comment: @fiXedd has apparently tried that and it doesn't work.  (See my answer's edit history.)  Maybe something to do with running on App Engine...

Answer (score 1):

A solution is mentioned in another thread [URL Pattern for servlet mapping in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491773/url-pattern-for-servlet-mapping-in-web-xml) using URLrewrite -> http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: Thanks for turning me on to this urlrewrite thing.  This got my java webapp with durandal to work, I was having some weird problem with it adding the routing alias infront of the url.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can't redirect to WEB-INF. A servlet container will never serve requests for documents in that folder.</strike>

If you want your application (not just a servlet, but the entire application) to be available under the root context ("/" of "http://www.domainname.com/"), then you need to set up a context entry for it - not a servlet mapping.

With Tomcat, you add a new [`<Context>` mapping](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) (in one of about 3 different possible places).

Comment: I'm not doing a redirect, I'm doing a forward. That's internal, so it souldn't matter if they're publicaly visible, right? Either way, moving them out of the WEB-INF didn't help.

I'm not using Tomcat, but I'll look in to context mapping, thanks.

Comment: The container will serve resources under WEB-INFs when the request is being forwarded. It's a valid, and useful site structure paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below?  (Note the missing `*`, which is a wild card and is the reason that your configuration catches everything.)

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

(Edited as per comments from just `/`.)

Comment: I did... it had the exact same result. I should have mentioned I'm doing this on App Engine. I'm starting to think they're mapping is, uh, wonky.