# Servlet path "/" returns that servlet content for any request pattern

Tags: jsp, servlets, document-root, url-pattern

When I map servlet with path as like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Home1Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.project.servlets.Home1Servlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Home1Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And then when I request servlet from browser by any paths like:

```
http://localhost:8084/project/
http://localhost:8084/project/asd
http://localhost:8084/project/why
http://localhost:8084/project/hell
```

All these requests return same Home1Servlet content. Why?

How can map servlet only to path "/"?

I am using Apache Tomcat 6.0.26, Java EE 5. Context path is: /project

Comment: The "why" part of a question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140448/difference-between-and-in-servlet-mapping-url-pattern)

Comment: you need to elaborate more about other servlet that you have. Expectation is not clear.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030302/how-can-i-map-a-root-servlet-so-that-other-scripts-are-still-runnable/9503668#9503668

Comment: Related: [difference between / and /* in Servlet mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4140448).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to map servlet ONLY to root url then use empty mapping:

```
<url-pattern></url-pattern>
```

It's described in Servlet specification 12.2:

> The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to
>   the application's context root, that is, requests of the form
>   host:port/<context_root>/. In this case the path info is  /  and
>   the servlet path and context path is empty string ("").

Answer (score -1):

Your servlet url mapping is empty.

```
<url-mapping>/</url-mapping>
```

So this url

```
http://localhost:8084/project/<any_url_given>
```

doesn't point to any specific servlet class rather it tells you any url pattern it accept e.g http::/.

If your servlet mapping be like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>hell</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.project.servlets.Hell</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hell</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hell</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and if you enter the url

```
http://localhost:8084/project/hell
```

Then **`com.project.servlets.Hell`** servlet should be invoked.